# how to ignore all empty key and values from JSON where the key is empty in python

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that contains this data :

```
[{
    "text": "1",
    "entities": []
},
{
    "text": "2",
    "entities": []
},

{
    "text": "GIARETTON ANTONIO C.F. GRTNTN69A22H829L CODICE P.0.D. IT001E30069505",
    "entities": [
        {
            "text": "GIARETTON ANTONIO C.F. GRTNTN69A22H829L CODICE P.0.D. IT001E30069505",
            "type": "Purpose of the transfer",
            "start_idx": 0,
            "end_idx": 68
        }
    ]
}]
```

I want to ignore all the keys and values that do not have data within the entities so that the final out put will look like this :

```
[ {
    "text": "GIARETTON ANTONIO C.F. GRTNTN69A22H829L CODICE P.0.D. IT001E30069505",
    "entities": [
        {
            "text": "GIARETTON ANTONIO C.F. GRTNTN69A22H829L CODICE P.0.D. IT001E30069505",
            "type": "Purpose of the transfer",
            "start_idx": 0,
            "end_idx": 68
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? We would love to see what you have tried!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to write [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```
print([obj for obj in data if obj['entities']])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to do it, provided that the data structure is always the same:

```py
def unpck(a,key="entities"):
  b=[]
  for x in a:
    if len(x[key])>0:
      b.append(x)
  return(b)
```

This function returns a list of the dictionaries that have data in the "entities", or any other key you want.